# Can I verify if code was executed in lambda statement using MoQ and NUnit?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

Im new in C#, trying to test my async service call:

```
interface IService
{
    void doSomething(string param, Action success, Action failure);
}
```

I know its kind of javascript pattern, but can I test code looking similar to this:

Actual implementation

```
service.doSomething("Param", (() => view.showSuccess()), (() => view.showError());
```

Test

```
service
.Setup(s => s.doSomething(It.IsAny<string>, It.isAny<Action>, It.isAny<Action>)
.Callback(<string, Action, Action>((param, success, failure) => success())

view.verify(v => v.showSuccess(), Times.Once);
```

Test fails, looks like code in lambda is never executed, how can I test if my class do what I want depending on callback from service?

Comment: This sounds like you are expecting Moq to execute the code in the implementation, while you are mocking the interface. Is that correct?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but can I force Moq to use real implementation from my class instead of It.isAny?

Comment: If you want the real implementation, then use it and _mock it's dependencies_

Comment: Thanks, instead of using mocks I injected my simple implementation and works as a charm!